# "Резкое" применение силы к персонажу

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть персонаж и враг, когда персонаж касается врага, или находится в нём, он выталкивается из него с помощью `AddForce()`, но это происходит достаточно медленно, будто из тюбика зубную пасту выжимаешь.

Как сделать так что бы персонаж при соприкосновении с врагом резко отталкивался от него, но при этом на короткое расстояние(т.е. он резко "отскочил" от врага, но при этом не на большое расстояние), мне достаточно одной идеи, как это сделать. Я пытался просто увеличить `Vector2` в функции `AddForce()`, но персонаж улетал далеко в тёплые края:)

P.S. На обоих объектах висит `Rigidbody2D` и `CircleCollider2D`.

Comment: [`ForceMode.Impulse`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode.Impulse.html) вторым параметром, не?

Comment: Если он улетает, но потом останавливается, то значит он тормозится средой. Следовательно эту силу в такой ситуации надо резко увеличить, а лучше всего (если это возможно) сделать ее пропорциональной экспоненте расстояния от "врага".

Comment: Да, я использовал ForceMode.Impulse. Я вроде как понял о чём вы говорите, немного погуглив насчёт сопротивления среды, и нашёл функцию drag, попробую с ней "поковыряться".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Использование `Drag` в `Rigidbody` помогло решить проблему, к персонажу я применяю импульс с вектором `(300, 300)` и значением `Drag = 5`, плюс ко всему увеличил в этот момент `gravityScale` у персонажа, что привело к желаемому результату. Персонаж резко отскочил на короткое расстояние в нужном направлении.